# Import tag on "flattened" WSDLs

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, salesforce, apache-axis

I'm trying to use the Salesforce Partner WSDL with Axis2's WSDL2C tool.  Unmodified, the tool reports that there are missing schemaLocations for the import tags.  The code produced doesn't compile.

I've tried a few more times by adding IDs to the schema sections and trying to use those as schemaLocations, but I receive errors about the namespaces being incorrect.

What would be the most appropriate way to turn this "flattened WSDL" (all of the schemas are defined in the WSDL itself with no other SFDC references) into something that Axis2 might be able to use?

Here is an example of one of the import sections:

```
<schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">

    <import namespace="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" schemaLocation="partner.soap.sforce.com SalesForce.Partner.wsdl"/>
```

The partner WSDL has 3 schemas - partner.soap.sforce.com, sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com and fault.partner.soap.sforce.com.  The sobject and partner schemas import each other.

As mentioned, I tried to add IDs and 'schemaLocations="#id"' but the result is an error stating that the sobject section has a different namespace than advertised.

Comment: I think I've got this sorted.  I ended up moving all of the schemas to separate XSDs and it worked with the WSDL2C tool. :)